# nodejs ws library how use with proxy

Tags: node.js, websocket, proxy, ws

The program I wrote establishes a websocket connection with the server and reads or sends data. What I want to do is connect multiple clients to the server with different ip addresses (I think I need to solve this with a proxy). How can I do that.

The intro is as follows:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://"+ws_server, {
  origin: server_origin,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  headers:my_headers
});
```